# JS won't work on loaded html

Tags: jquery, html, load, jquery-select2

I'm using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), jQuery based selectbox.
And want to load a part of the page by selected multiple options.
That works fine, but javascript won't work on the loaded part.
How can I solve this?

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#e1").on("change", function(e){
   $(".map_border").load('.', {"age":e.val, "cat":$("#e2").select2("val") });
 });
});
$(function(){
  $("#e2").on("change", function(e){
   $(".map_border").load('.', {"cat":e.val, "age":$("#e1").select2("val") });
 });
});
</script>

<div class="selector">
 <select id="e1">
  <option value="1">小学生</option>
  <option value="2">中学生</option>
  <option value="3">高校生</option>
 </select>
 <select id="e2">
  <option value="1">算数</option>
  <option value="2">英文法</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class="map_border" style="height:{{max_loop}}px">
・・・loaded part・・・
</div>
```

Comment: See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331127/5836

Comment: Is this a matter of attaching events to elements that are loaded dynamically?

Comment: Thanks @Brettski. I've read it but I can't figure out how I should use .on. I'll try some more.

Comment: Thanks again @Brettski. I misunderstood .on or .live function. I can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User jQuery .live() or .on() depending on the version of jQuery you are using.

http://api.jquery.com/live/